# How to concatenate files in reverse order

Tags: terminal, cat, tac

I am looking to concatenate a list of files in a directory in the reverse order that they appear in the list.

This is different from `tac` as `tac` will concatenate the files with reversed line order.

Basically I have a folder with 3 files, `file1`, `file2` and `file3`.

`cat f* > newfile` will merge these files like so:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

However, I want to merge the files like this

```
file3
file2
file1
```

whilst maintaining the correct line order.

Answer (score 5):

> This is different to `tac` as `tac` will concatenate the files with reversed line order

… and not in the desired reverse sequence of files. Surprisingly this is *good*, because an additional `tac` acting on the whole output will give you exactly what you want:

```
tac f* | tac
```

Comment: So elegant! ...

Comment: And this is *not* a useless use of tac.

Answer (score 2):

Try "Brace Expansion" (cf. `man bash`):

```
set -vx
cat file{3..1}
+ cat file3 file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `ls` to sort them out and then concatenate with `cat`:

```
ls -1r | xargs -d'\n' cat
```

If you ever want to use another sort order, or shuffle the entries, you change the left part of the pipe.

In this case `-1` will list a filename in each line and the `-r` does inverts the order (since it is not specified, it is alphabetical, according to your locale).